# Meteor: subscribe with query fails

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In my meteor app I'm implementing functionality to send messages between users.
In my app I have a route and template that displays all messages sent to the user.

The controller code:

```
this.UserMessagesController = RouteController.extend({
    template: "UserMessages",
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe("userMessages");
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            "messages": UserMessages.find({to: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {time: -1}} )
        }
    }
});
}
});
```

On the server side I have a publish functions

```
Meteor.publish("userMessages", function() {
    var userId = this.userId;
    return UserMessages.find({to: userId}, {});
});
```

Also I have a global subscription to unread messages:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        Meteor.subscribe("unreadMessages");
    }
});

Meteor.publish("unreadMessages", function() {
    return UserMessages.find({to: this.userId, read: undefined}, {});
});
```

The problem is: I can see only unread messages rendered on template (and unread message only in client minimongo collection as well)

But if I remove filter {to: userId} from publish function or remove subscription to unread messages I can perfectly see each message!

PS: I tried to debug publish function setting breakpoint and evaluating UserMessages.find({to: userId}, {}).fetch() and I got absolutely correct array consisting of 15 messages.

PPS: I got no error messages on the server side as well as on client side

What might be a problem?

Comment: Can you post your unread messages subscription? You said "...or remove subscription to unread messages ..." I suspect that subscription is somehow overwriting the data you want here.

Comment: Yeah, Deps.autorun(function() {
 if (Meteor.user()) {
  Meteor.subscribe("current_user_data");
  Meteor.subscribe("unreadMessages");
 }
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Subscribe

   ```
   this.UserMessagesController = RouteController.extend({
   template: "UserMessages",

   subscriptions: function(){

   return [
       Meteor.subscribe("user.message")
     ]
   },

   data: function() {

    return UserMessages.find();

   })
   ```
2. Publish

   ```
   Meteor.publish("user.message", function(){

     var criteria = {};
     var projection = {};

     var userId = this.userId;
     _.extend(criteria, {to: userId});
     _.extend(projection, { 
       sort: {
         time: -1
         } 
      });

     return UserMessages.find(criteria, projection);

   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I understand that problem is in projection. If it is empty then I have my problem. Can you explain why?

Comment: Also I have another problem - if I add projection to my unreadMessages subscription then all read messages disappear again. But without it I have incorrect Message ordering (I have unread messages first, but I want messages to appear it time order)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
Meteor.publish("userMessages", function(id) {
    return UserMessages.find({to: id}, {});
});
```

and then
pass the id parameter in the subscribe request

```
waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe("userMessages", Meteor.userId());
    },
```

but for troublshooting these stuff, your best friend is MeteorToys to debug stuff:
they have a free version, get it with

```
meteor add meteortoys:allthings
```

and hit CRTL + M (on Mac OS)

it will show you everything that is sent to the browser so you can troubleshoot much more easily.

Comment: pass the id as a parameter to you subscription too in the Router code

Comment: Thank you, but It didn't helped(( I find the source of problem - I have two active subscriptions on this table, I describe it in details In the question.